# Terminal Warning: "Gti-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

Tags: gtk3

When I run programs that use GTK from the terminal, I almost always see warnings (sometimes many warnings) like this:

```
Gtk-Message: 09:18:04.593: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
```

This happens with evince and many others. How can these warnings be silenced?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18.10 includes a package that was not currently installed on the system. Installing the package `libatk-adaptor` eliminates the warnings. There may be a small error in packaging for programs that implement or rely on GTK.